# How can I outsource a specific calculation to another Google Sheets to reduce the computing effort?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context:** I plan to create a tool inside the Google Sheets "universe" that will (likely) consist of 3 different sheets:

1. A database containing multiple data points for different customers
2. A sheet that performs calculations on a subset of data from sheet 1 for a specific customer. Basically it takes data from sheet 1 for one specific customer (by filter) and then performs some "low effort" calculations to the data
3. A sheet that performs one specific calculation (for Sheet B) that is quite "computing heavy",
   thus outsourced to a different sheet. This sheet 3 contains other data points that are necessary for the specific calculation.

**Problem:** I want to perform the calculation of sheet 3 for multiple data points (10-100) of sheet 2. I hoped that I could create a function (or a customized function via script?) that would take input data from sheet 2 (five values/cells) -> send it to sheet 3 -> perform calculations inside sheet 3 -> send back the solution (one value/cell) to sheet 2 (without having to open sheet 3).

I could, in theory, consolidate sheet 2 and 3 into one sheet (it works in Excel), but it seems to be to "computing heavy" for Google Sheets. Thus I had the idea to outsource the calculation to another sheet.

**Question:** Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem?

I'm open for any suggestions!

Many thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: If your question is about scripting then one thing to keep in main that all container bound scripts in a given project have access to all of sheets in the container.

Comment: If the computation is really heavy, you will not solve it by outsourcing it to another sheet. You must reach out to cloud functions like https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions or https://cloud.google.com/run (or other cloud providers) and call that function via UrlFetchApp.fetch.
If it is REALLY heavy (taking several minutes or so), you need to implement sort of callback. Anyway, we need a more specific description to get you an accurate answer